# Hibernate many-to-many SQLGrammerException

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a table called `registereduser`

```
REATE TABLE registereduser
(
  registereduserid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('registereduser_registereduserid_seq'::regclass),
  username character varying(320) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(500) NOT NULL,
...
)
```

then i have table which maps the many-to-many relationship with roles

```
CREATE TABLE registereduser_role
(
  registereduser_roleid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('registereduser_role_registereduser_roleid_seq'::regclass),
  registereduserid bigint NOT NULL,
  role bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT registereduser_role_pkey PRIMARY KEY (registereduser_roleid),
  CONSTRAINT registereduser_role_registereduserid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (registereduserid)
      REFERENCES public.registereduser (registereduserid) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

The role table is fairly simple

```
CREATE TABLE public.role
(
  roleid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('role_roleid_seq'::regclass),
  rolename character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  friendlydescription character varying(80),
  CONSTRAINT role_pkey PRIMARY KEY (roleid),
  CONSTRAINT role_rolename_key UNIQUE (rolename)
)
```

My **RegisteredUser.java** class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="registereduser")
public class RegisteredUser {
  @Id
  @Column(name="registereduserid")
  private long registeredUserId;

  @Column(name="username")
  private String userName;

  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
    name="registereduser_role",
    joinColumns =
      @JoinColumn(name="registereduserid", referencedColumnName = "registereduserid"),
    inverseJoinColumns =
      @JoinColumn(name="role", referencedColumnName = "roleid")
  )
  private List<Role> roles;
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "roleid")
  private long roleId;

  @Column(name = "rolename")
  private String roleName;

  @Column(name = "friendlydescription")
  private String friendlyDescription;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "roles")
  private List<RegisteredUser> registeredUsers;
...
}
```

When i try to fetch roles, I am getting sqlgrammer exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column roles1_.roleid does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "roles1_.role" or the column "role2_.roleid".
  Position: 518
```

How can i fix this.

p.s:

The sql which is being issued by hibernate is

```
Hibernate: select registered0_.registereduserid as register1_0_0_, registered0_.password as password2_0_0_, registered0_.username as username3_0_0_, roles1_.registeredUserId as register1_0_1_, role2_.roleid as roleId2_1_1_, role2_.roleid as roleid1_2_2_, role2_.friendlydescription as friendly2_2_2_, role2_.role as role3_2_2_, role2_.rolename as rolename4_2_2_ from registereduser registered0_ left outer join registereduser_role roles1_ on registered0_.registereduserid=roles1_.registeredUserId left outer join role role2_ on roles1_.roleId=role2_.roleid where registered0_.registereduserid=?
```

Comment: Can you post your Role Entity?

Comment: I have added it to the original post

Comment: I don't see any error by analyzing your code... what looks weird to me is that hibernate seems to not obey the columns capitalization... Example: `roles1_.roleId=role2_.roleid` ... Are you sure that your deployment has the correct version of your code ?

Comment: i am out of ideas as well. yeah, I am using spring-boot and running the app from IDE (intellij) ... so everytime i execute, intellij runs `mvn clean install` and then runs the `Application.java`

Comment: How about rename your `role`  column to `roleid` at the `registereduser_role` table.... Can you do that? (That approach I think will solve the problem, but left the question about Why is not working..)

Comment: I guess, I have figured out the issue. I am going to test it and would report back :) ...

Comment: okay so it turned out that i had a nested enum class with in my `Role` class. The `Role` class had a private variable called `roles` which was of type enum. I didn't realized that i hadn't put `@Transient` on that variable. Once i removed it it worked fine :)